# Docker swarm service on different nodes can't communicate

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I'm running docker in swarm mode where I have some services running on the same overlay network but different nodes.

I'm trying to get the nodes of these services to be able to talk to each other; which works fine until I try to talk cross node.

Here is the definition of my network, as gotten from one node:

```
{
    "Name": "my-nw",
    "Id": "0jk0h0sor0839i2j91rz8b7c9",
    "Scope": "swarm",
    "Driver": "overlay",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "10.0.0.0/24",
                "Gateway": "10.0.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Containers": {
        "0467076e0f3b3618115a4d023e78a74921eb6ef7c7ba1e5baeffe1ea4500ee1e": {
            "Name": "sleepy_fermi.2.59adig1cqoe6s5frqvwco3fyk",
            "EndpointID": "7276764bd319c57f3343ff871db136e0a224eedb52e93dc8bb1e0d488bf6de83",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:04",
            "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.4/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "4554f04efa9c2d66e584fefa3d610314761f8dc6599f3723e878e6e5326cd21e": {
            "Name": "sleepy_fermi.3.4jdpxy1zbu33tf55cbp24llbk",
            "EndpointID": "b498650bac96aa780a88f0c7a0c70dc716e00b3a4852dcaaf22450d71712ef5f",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:05",
            "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.5/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "257",
        "encrypted": ""
    },
    "Labels": {}
}
```

And here it is from another node:

```
{
    "Name": "my-nw",
    "Id": "0jk0h0sor0839i2j91rz8b7c9",
    "Scope": "swarm",
    "Driver": "overlay",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "10.0.0.0/24",
                "Gateway": "10.0.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Containers": {
        "68ae6de87b418168fdc708ea015d3b4130911124eab9821902d03de59eb91264": {
            "Name": "sleepy_fermi.1.azu3d6fdjq1jovspok3xn0rrk",
            "EndpointID": "dc485439790fa586c8c592f2e53f8bdb7e50142c560538349a70e2cda6e065a4",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.3/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "f4fdacd84bf8b40dace568d3ced1635bec0f982f03566e043e59c29eccc2bf19": {
            "Name": "tiny_montalcini.1.a3ovorl23ak351gozxr9o7nvt",
            "EndpointID": "f3951430836fbb056e559e43de921b8c437f72d1ee0c59b4179220c6c0ea0eee",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:07",
            "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.7/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "257",
        "encrypted": ""
    },
    "Labels": {}
}
```

So, for example, I can curl sleepy_fermi.4. from sleepy_fermi.5. but not from sleepy_fermi.3 (the ip-address doesn't work either so it's not just a name lookup issue).

Comment: Where are you running this setup? If a firewall is blocking the ports needed for Swarm to work then this wont work

Comment: services which need to communicate with each other need to run in the same network

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm having a similar issue right now.